# Is it Possible: Link object files, then link result to more object files?

Tags: compilation, linker, partial, object-files

I'm new to the linking and compilation process (if you've got good learning sources, please share!), and am playing around with makefiles. I apologize in advanced that the following sounds obvious.

Say I compile 2 `.o` files, and then link them. Then, I compile another `.o` file. Can I link the initial result with the third object file?

Comment: You compile all files, and then link them. Linking is the final step. You can compile object files and add then to a library (.lib) file, but it's still only used after all compilation is done.

Comment: There are several possibilities here, any or even all of which might
be irrelevant to your actual needs. What you mean by
"Say I compile 2 .o files, and then link them" is unclear. Please
post specimen commandlines or `make` recipes that show what you
mean by this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it Possible: Link object files, then link result to more object files?

Yes:

```
ld -r -o foo-combined.o foo1.o foo2.o
gcc foo-combined.o bar.o -o a.out
```

The `-r` flag creates a relocatable (object) file, which effectively merges `foo1.o` and `foo2.o`.